# Integration problem: $\int x^{2} -x 4^{-x^{2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to integrate $$\int x^{2} -x 4^{-x^{2}} dx$$ 
and I know the answer I got is wrong. However, I can't figure out where I went wrong. These steps I took:

[image]

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is the question $\int x^{2} -x 4^{-x^{2}} dx$?

Comment: yes! sorry for unclear handwriting

Comment: is there a reason this is getting down voted?

Comment: Probably because you didn't put the question in latex.. See here for a tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I can't read your solution properly so I'll put up the solution for you

Comment: I'd put in in latex but it'd take an hour

Comment: .. And? Then it takes an hour.

Comment: Looks basically OK. In the last line the $2$ travelled  from downstairs to upstairs for no reason.

Comment: So other than that, it could be right? Because I am plugging $\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{2\space }-4^{-x^2}x\right)$  and $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{e^{-\ln \left(4x^2\right)}}{2\ln 4}$ into a graphing calculator and they are not the same graph

Comment: You're putting the $\frac{d}{dx}$ in front of the wrong formula. Try it the other way around. (The derivative of the _answer_ should give you back the original integrand.)

Comment: BTW, use cut and paste appropriately and you can put it in LaTeX in a lot less than an hour. There are very few different things actually in those equations, they just repeat a lot.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\int x^{2} - x4^{-x^{2}} dx &= \int x^{2} dx - \int x4^{-x^{2}} dx \\
&= \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \int -x4^{-x^{2}} dx \\
\end{align}$$

notice that

$$\frac{d}{dx} 4^{-x^{2}} = -2x\cdot \ln4 \cdot 4^{-x^{2}}$$

So if

$$\begin{align}
u &= 4^{-x^{2}} \\
\implies du &= -2x\cdot \ln4 \cdot 4^{-x^{2}} dx \\
\implies \frac{du}{2 \ln4} &= -x 4^{-x^{2}} dx
\end{align}$$

So our integral becomes

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^{3}}{3} + \int -x4^{-x^{2}} dx &= \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \int \frac{du}{2 \ln4} \\
&= \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{u}{2 \ln4} + C \\
&= \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{4^{-x^{2}}}{2 \ln4} + C \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it as follows:
\begin{align}
\int \left(x^2-\frac{x}{4^{x^2}}\right)\,dx &= \int x^2\,dx - \int 4^{-x^2}x \,dx\\[1em]
               &= \frac{x^3}{3}-\int 4^{-x^2}x\,dx\\[1em]
               &= \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\int 4^u\,du\tag{$u=-x^2; du=-2x\,dx$}\\[1em]
               &= \frac{2^{2u-1}}{\log(4)}+\frac{x^3}{3}+C\\[1em]
               &= \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2^{-2x^2-1}}{\log(4)}+C\tag{subst. back $u=-x^2$}\\[1em]
               &= \frac{x^3\log(4)+3\cdot 2^{-2x^2-1}}{\log(64)}+C,
\end{align}
As you can see, the real trick is to use $u$-substitution effectively, which I imagine is the point of this exercise.

Comment: There are some typos in the first two equalities.

Comment: @John Is there another typo I missed? (Thanks for pointing it out btw)